# Is it possible to get a sorted list of attribute values from a JSON array using JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given JSON like:

```
[
    {
        "Serial no": 994,
    },
    {
        "Serial no": 456,
    }
]
```

I know this query will give me an array of all `Serial no` values, in the order they are in the JSON: `$..['Serial no']`

I'm not sure exactly what sorting capabilities JSONPath has but I think you can use `/` and `\` to sort - but how are they used to modify my query string in this case? I am only interested doing this in pure JSONPath, not JS or post-query sorting - that's easy, I just want to know if I can avoid it.

[This is a source](https://gabbi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsonpath.html) I found suggesting sorting is supported but it might be product-specific?

I'm using http://www.jsonquerytool.com/ to test this

Comment: That's not JSON (JSON does not allow dangling commas). And AFAIK, basic JSONPath has no sorting capabilities, though some libraries (like `jsonpath` for Python) do add those extensions.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that dangling comma. It's from a huge real-world dataset I had to sanitise.